# How to modify an existing response in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm working on a script that creates and submits form responses automatically based on the data taken from a source. I already manage to make it work using the methods available:

```
formResponse.withItemResponse(items[0].asTextItem().createResponse("Sample"))
            .submit();
```

...

I was wondering if there's **any method to edit parameters of an existing entry**.
I've tried to access specific responses using the timeStamp as identifier but I can't manage to change the existing parameter and submit the response:

```
form.getResponses(timeStamp)[0].withItemResponse(items[0].asTextItem().createResponse("Sample Modified"))
                               .submit();
```

My understanding is that the submit() method only applies for new entries. Is there a workaround to perform what I'm trying to do?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it maybe an option to use a script in sheets to change the parameters in the spreadsheet?

Comment: What would the script look like?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Moppel26, unfortunately I would need to access in the future the answer stored in the response itself through a link is generated after each response is submitted. Changing only the visible information from the spreadsheet wouldn't affect the stored data.

Comment: @JenniferGoncalves: Thanks for your comment. I posted a generic simplified script just to contextualize my question. I don't think adding the actual script would give more info as is not related to the topic. Thanks